# use different css when button clicked with different media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

Good afternoon. I have a little problem that is causing me a headache. I have a DIV with an ID of 'booking-md' This changes size with media query and works well like so.

```
<div id="booking-md" class="container-fluid booking-md"></div>
```

and media queries change it like so:-

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .booking-md { height: 320px}
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .booking-md { height: 220px}
}

@media screen and (max-width:560px) {
    .booking-md { height: 320px}
}
```

I also have a button which makes the 'booking-md' height bigger like so

```
<button type="button" onclick="ret()" class="btn btn-return">Return</button>

function ret() {
$('#booking-md').css('height', '175px');
$('#return').show()
}
```

Now this adds 50px to the size ok but when It resizes it does not use the original media queries to change size. Ideally I need to have 2 different sets of media queries, one for if button has been clicked and one if not.

I have tried this with changing the class but doesnt do much after changing the size once. It looks like it loses all the media queries.

```
document.getElementById("booking-md").className = "booking-sm";
```

Is using php with this an option? Im at a loss and seem to have tryied everything, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@wayneuk2, please have a look at the below working snippet, have made a few minor updates to your own code, hope it helps :)

```css
.set-height {
  height: 175px;
}
.booking-md {
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .booking-md {
    height: 320px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .booking-md {
    height: 220px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:560px) {
  .booking-md {
    height: 320px
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="booking-md" class="container-fluid booking-md">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="ret()" class="btn btn-primary btn-return">Return</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function ret() {
    $('#booking-md').addClass('set-height');
    $('#return').show()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but what does it do? It sets height to nothing?? Am I supposed to put the height somewhere? Was just working with javascript on this but not really working either

Comment: And have tried something like this, if I do it like this it ignores all the media query settings and like I said I need to be able to switch between the 2 depending on the button

Answer (score 0):

wow that was easy!! Dont know why I was trying the hard ways, I simply too out the change the height in the media queries and just set the 'booking-md' height like this to fit in the content.

```
.booking-md {height:auto;overflow: hidden;)
```

Works like a charm